# Web scraping multiple tags that have the same class name

Tags: python, web-scraping

Just a disclaimer I'm still pretty new to Python.
I'm web scraping using BeautifulSoup in the bs4 module and I'm looking in inspect element and I want to print the text for the 2nd `<ul>` tag. There's 4 `<ul>`tags in total, all of them have the same class name. How would I go about printing the tag that I want? Or two or three of them?

this is the code that I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sys import argv

import requests

word_initial = argv[1]

url = requests.get(f'https://www.merriamwebster.com/thesaurus/{word_initial}').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, features='html.parser')

word = soup.find('h1', class_='hword')
syn = soup.find("ul", class_='mw-list')

print(word.text.upper())
print(syn.text)
```

Comment: you can simply do indexing, e.g. '//ul[2]' will get you the second tag of all uls'

Comment: so the line of code would look like this?
word = soup.find("ul[2]", class_='mw-list')

Comment: my bad. i thought it was xpath; since soup.find return a list of values, so you can do word[1] which return the second value.

Comment: For me soup.find doesn't return a list, it just gives me text

Comment: Why don't you try selectors like ```soup.find_all('ul',class_="mw-list'")```. it will return ```list``` and that ```list[1]``` will return second element

Comment: We cannot write answers to your questions if you won't share your code or at least the website link that you're scraping. Please do add code that you tried or link

Comment: Thanks. I just posted my code. Also neither soup.find_all nor soup.find_All seem to work. I get a TypeError for the latter and an AttributeError for the former

Comment: do you try to use `find_all(..).text` ? It will not work - you have to use `text` on every elements on list separatelly -  `items = find_all(..)` and `word = items[1].text` or `all_words = [word.text for word in items]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check your url -> `https://www.merriam-webster.com/` not `https://www.merriamwebster.com/`

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sys import argv    
import requests

word_initial ='test' 

url = requests.get(f'https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/{word_initial}').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, features='html.parser')

word = soup.find('h1', class_='hword')
syn = soup.find("ul", class_='mw-list')

print(word.text.upper())
print(syn.text)
```

**Output**

```
TEST
essay, experiment, experimentation, trial
```

### edited

if you want to extract the 2nd ul, then you might want to do `.find_all()` instead of `.find()`:

```
...
syn = soup.find_all("ul", class_="mw-list") # this returns list of values
second_ul = syn[2]
third_ul = syn[3]
print(second_ul.get_text(),third_ul.get_text())
...
```

Output:

```
dry run, shakedown exercise, practice (also practise), rehearsal, tryout, workout
```